# Python Selenium Webdriver Wait Poll Frequency

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

Is there a minimum value for the WebdriverWait in Python Selenium? By default it is set as **0.5s**

`def __init__(self, driver, timeout, poll_frequency=POLL_FREQUENCY, ignored_exceptions=None):`

Also, is there any substantial drawback to reducing the polling time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter `POLL_FREQUENCY` is expected to be `float` which minimal value can be queried with `sys.float_info.min`. In my system it returns `2.2250738585072014e-308`.

There is no "algorithmic" drawback since `WebDriver` is actually a `REST` service and you use it in synchronous way. However too short period would result in to much useless calls to a driver which could impact the performance of your system, introduce noise to your logs, consume more network traffic, etc.